# how do I get custom include paths to work in visual studio code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include

I am trying to figure out how to get gcc to recognize my GLFW include. intellisense currently says there aren't any issues. here is what my current code looks like in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Include\glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world");
    getch();
}
```

And when I try to compile it:

```
PS D:\github\c> cd "d:\github\c\" ; if ($?) { gcc main.c -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
main.c:2:10: fatal error: glfw3.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've tried editing c_cpp_properties.json, here's what it currently looks like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "D:\\github\\c\\Include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And I couldn't get this to work, so I also tried editing tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "-I\"${workspaceFolder}/include**\"",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

this, also did not work.

And lastly I tried typing it manually, which did properly compile for no reason I can understand.

```
PS D:\github\c> gcc main.c -o main.exe -I"Include" -I"libs"
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getch'; did you mean 'getc'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    7 |     getch();
      |     ^~~~~
      |     getc
```

edit: I just tried again and it no longer compiles when I type the command manually. what is happening??

Comment: you have include directories specified in your c_cpp_properties.json that you didn't specify in your tasks.json. c_cpp_properties.json is for intellisense. your tasks.json is for doing the build. they should match. Also, why is you error message showing `#include <glfw3.h>` when your code shows `#include <Include\glfw3.h>`?

Comment: I tried moving the file around to get it to work and I might've copied some of the wrong stuff from my console by accident. I tried updating my tasks.json to this:

           ` "args": [
                
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}\\Include",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}\\Libs",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}\\**",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"`
but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `getch` is a deprecated alias for `_getch`, which comes from the windows-specific `conio.h` header (not standard c++). docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch?view=msvc-170. Try adding `#include <conio.h>`.

Comment: Also, your c_cpp_properties.json has `D:\\github\\c\\Include`, but in the comment you just made, you didn't specify that one with an include directory flag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am kinda newbie too but i have a suggestion. Try:
`#include "Include\glfw3.h"` instead of `#include <Include\glfw3.h>`. I think that is how you import your own header files.